# Odds of getting at least one triple consecutive wins.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Given P(winning game) = p and P(losing game) = 1-p.

If you play 10 rounds of games only, what is the probability of getting at **least** one triple consecutive wins? in terms of p.

Where WWWLLLLLLL = one triple consecutive win.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to calculate the probability of no three consecutive wins.

To solve it you should only notice that any 10 games that have no three consecutive wins must start with "L", "WL", "WWL".

I think you can now proceed using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to calculate the complimentary probability of no triples in a string of length $n$. Let the number of losses in the string be $k$.  There are $k+1$ gaps where we should place $n-k$ wins (no more than 2 wins per gap). Applying stars and bars and inclusion-exclusion principle one finds that the number of ways to arrange wins and losses is:
$$
N(n,k)=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}(-1)^j\binom{k+1}j\binom{n-3j}k,
$$
so that the complimentary probability can be computed as
$$
P(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n N(n,k)p^{n-k}(1-p)^k.
$$